# How to show child relationship in table using DataTables

Tags: php, sql-server, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a table that shows Invoice information. Right now it easily shows each row with all the info. The problem that I have is that some of the invoices have the same number, but different Project numbers. I need a way to show a row that has the invoice number and total for the invoice and then shows rows under it that have the individual Project numbers and the amounts for each of those.

I have a SQL table that houses all the data that I need here's an example:

```
+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+--------+
|  Id  | State | InvoiceNumber | ProjectWONumber | InvoiceDate | TotalProjectAmount | Capital  | Expense | Status |
+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+--------+
| 1938 | CT    |      00000462 |         3109473 | 2017-05-25  |            657.190 | NULL     | 657.190 | Paid   |
| 3613 | CT    |      00000462 |         3107492 | 2017-05-25  |            657.190 | NULL     | 657.190 | Paid   |
| 3614 | CT    |      00000462 |         3106222 | 2017-05-25  |           1690.970 | 1690.970 | NULL    | Paid   |
| 3615 | CT    |      00000462 |         3107795 | 2017-05-25  |           1302.380 | 1302.380 | NULL    | Paid   |
| 3616 | CT    |      00000462 |         3096444 | 2017-05-25  |            675.190 | NULL     | 675.190 | Paid   |
| 3617 | CT    |      00000462 |         3109473 | 2017-05-25  |            328.590 | NULL     | 328.590 | Paid   |
+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+--------+
```

As you can see the Invoice Numbers are all the same, but the Project Numbers are all different. When I put this on the php website it works fine and looks like this:

[image: Invoices]

What I want it to do it have one row that has the parent invoice number with the totals and then the rest follow it, but showing somehow that they are connected as children of the parent.

Something like this maybe:

```
+-----+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------+
| PId |  Id  | State | InvoiceNumber | ProjectWONumber | InvoiceDate | TotalProjectAmount | Capital  | Expense  | Status |
+-----+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------+
|   1 |      | CT    |      00000462 |                 | 2017-05-25  |           5311.510 | 2993.350 | 2318.160 |        |
|     | 1938 | CT    |      00000462 |         3109473 | 2017-05-25  |            657.190 |          |  657.190 | Paid   |
|     | 3613 | CT    |      00000462 |         3107492 | 2017-05-25  |            657.190 |          |  657.190 | Paid   |
|     | 3614 | CT    |      00000462 |         3106222 | 2017-05-25  |           1690.970 | 1690.970 |          | Paid   |
|     | 3615 | CT    |      00000462 |         3107795 | 2017-05-25  |           1302.380 | 1302.380 |          | Paid   |
|     | 3616 | CT    |      00000462 |         3096444 | 2017-05-25  |            675.190 |          |  675.190 | Paid   |
|     | 3617 | CT    |      00000462 |         3109473 | 2017-05-25  |            328.590 |          |  328.590 | Paid   |
+-----+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------+
```

The Id of the first (parent) row would be filled in with a number, but I don't have one currently. Also, I would probably have the child records offset to the right slightly so that it is easy to see which are parent records and which are child records. Maybe have the parents show with a button to one side to expand and show the children, I'm not sure. I've tried looking into using the ChildRows with RowGrouping from DataTables but was not able to figure out how to do this.

Any suggestions of help would be appreciated.

I have begun a test on the [DataTables Live](http://live.datatables.net/jigogeye/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) to try to show what I have.

Comment: PHP + SQL-Server = interesting combination

Comment: @Eli Yes it does, but so far it works just fine. Well, except for this one problem here.